# How do I make my Server that is connected to the Internet using an LTE modem publicly available?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, webserver, mobile-broadband

I have a Server running Linux that is connected to the Internet using an LTE modem and a German 4G provider. From that provider I'm not getting a publicly accessible IP, neither static nor dynamic. I know that there are providers that claim to offer this (https://www.mdex.de/shop/m2m-sim-karten/) and also there appear to be providers that claim to offer some VPN tunneling solution that should route the traffic over some server with a public IP address to my unreachable server... somehow even for LTE connections (https://www.internet-xs.de/vpn-internet-zugang/feste-oeffentliche-ipv4-adresse/feste-ip-fuer-linux-server.html).

My question is, what kind of tunneling are they using and can I replicate it myself using a second server that does have a public IP?

Comment: [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm)

Comment: They are using a VPN server, so you'd need to install and run one of those on your second server, and you'd still need a VPN client on your first server.